# 'Alex is a son of Smith.' and 'Smith is a father of Alex.' carry same meaning or different meaning?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

In terms of Data Modeling, either of the following two relationships imply the same meaning. I mean I can use any one of them. (For Specific two Individuals)

1. IS_A_SON_OF
2. IS_A_FATHER_OF

### Example

1. Alex IS_A_SON_OF Smith.

Which gives (implies to) me

- Alex is related to Smith as a Son.
- Smith is related to Alex as a Father.

  2. Smith IS_A_FATHER_OF Alex.

Which gives (implies to) me

- Alex is related to Smith as a Son.
- Smith is related to Alex as a Father.

### My Question:

If the native English speaker uses

1. Alex is a son of Smith.

or

2. Smith is the father of Alex.

Do the above two sentences carry different meanings?

Comment: I think you mean *imply*, not *infer*.

Comment: @StoneyB Changed infer to imply.

Comment: I don't think so. Both exactly convey one concept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both "son" and "father" convey two pieces of information:

1. The family relationship between **two** individuals.
2. The gender of **one** individual (the subject of the sentence).

So your first sentence

> Alex is a son of Smith.

has these implications:

1. Smith is Alex's parent.
2. Alex is male.
3. Smith could be male or female.

Your second sentence:

> Smith is the father of Alex.

has these implications:

1. Smith is Alex's parent.
2. Smith is male.
3. Alex could be male or female.

So in each case, implication 1 is identical, but 2 and 3 are different.